# Algorithm with file input skipping conditions - C language

Tags: c, algorithm, file, loops, conditional-statements

While going through examples and exercises in our textbook I came upon what appeared to be a simple problem:

> Copy first K characters from first K lines of file input.txt into file out1.txt and rest of characters on the lines into out2.txt. Skip following L lines and then copy first L characters of the remaining lines into out1.txt and rest of the text into out2.txt.
>   All while keeping formatting (number of \n characters) same in all files.

I came up with following algorithm and tested it on the provided file.
Amusingly the program doesn't care for conditions at all, instead it simply copies first K characters into out1.txt and the rest into out2.txt.
My attempts to debug the program were unsuccessful because Codeblocs doesn't seem to see the input file and just skips the whole algorithm because the initial condition is not fulfilled.

It is driving me crazy and I honestly cannot see what I did wrong.
Before you ask no it is not homework.

Note: `i` is counter of characters, `l` and `k` are constants.

```
while (chr != EOF) {
    if ((line < k) && (i < k)) {
        fputc(chr, out1);
    } else
    if ((line < k) && (i > k)) {
        fputc(chr, out2);
    } else
    if ((line > (l+k)) && (i < l)) {
        fputc(chr, out1);
    } else
    if ((line > (l+k)) && (i > l)) {
        fputc(chr, out2);
    } else
    if (chr == '\n') {
        fputc(chr, out1);
        fputc(chr, out2);
        line = line + 1;
        i = 0;
    }
    i = i + 1;
    chr = fgetc(input);
}
```

Comment: It's likely that the behavior is different when running in the debugger because the working directory is different. For the time being, try opening the file with its full path.

Comment: Your logic is imprecise: what should happen if `i == k` or `i == l`?  Your code is badly formated, hard to read.  What is `znak` ?  You should post more code.

Comment: Sorry about that znak thing that was original name of chr variable. English is not my first language you see. Also I know that the condition don't cover everything. My approach was to first see if I was on right track and then to expand the logic to cover every possibility. Also I will try to put full path for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test for `'\n'` first in the loop.  Otherwise the linefeeds are output as part of the lines and the line count does not get updated correctly.

```
int chr;
int line = 0;
int i = 0;    

while ((chr = getc(input)) != EOF) {
    if (chr == '\n') {
        fputc(chr, out1);
        fputc(chr, out2);
        line = line + 1;
        i = 0;
    } else {
        if ((line < k) && (i < k)) {
            fputc(chr, out1);
        } else
        if ((line < k) && (i >= k)) {
            fputc(chr, out2);
        } else
        if ((line >= (l+k)) && (i < l)) {
            fputc(chr, out1);
        } else
        if ((line >= (l+k)) && (i >= l)) {
            fputc(chr, out2);
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as intended now! Thinking about it know it seems really apparent, the most rare/weirdly behaving case should be tested first. Thanks again.

Comment: Not just the most *rare/weird* case...  You must handle actual characters differently from the line feed char, therefore you must check first what category `chr` belongs to.  You could also write fewer tests if you nest them differently for the `else` branch handling regular characters.